# The chain rule of differentiation

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

What is wrong with my solution?

$$
S=f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \frac{x y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & ((x, y) \neq(0,0)) \\
0 & ((x, y)=(0,0))
\end{array}\right.
$$

$x=2t, y=3t$

---

1. $\displaystyle\left(\frac{d S}{dt}\right)_{t=0}$

My solution:

When $t \neq 0$, $$S = \frac{2t \times 3t}{(2t)^2 + (3t)^2} = \frac{6}{13}$$

$$\displaystyle\left(\frac{d S}{dt}\right)_{t=0} = 0$$

When $t = 0 $, $$S=0$$
$$\displaystyle\left(\frac{d S}{dt}\right)_{t=0} = 0$$

The answer: $$\displaystyle\left(\frac{d S}{dt}\right)_{t=0} = 0$$

2. When $t=0$, how $\displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d t}$ would be?

My solution:

When $t \neq 0$,
$$\begin{eqnarray} \displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d t} 
&=& \frac{y\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)-x y \times 2 x}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}} \times 2+\frac{x\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)-xy \times 2y}{\left(x^{2}+y\right)^{2}} \times 3 \\
&=& \frac{2 y\left(y^{2}-x^{2}\right)}{\left(x+y^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{3 x\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}{\left( x^2+y^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
&=& \frac{3 x^{3}-2 x^{2} y-3 x y^{2}+2 y^{3}}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d t} = 0$$

When $t = 0 $, $$S=0$$
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d t} = 0$$

The answer: $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d t} = 0$$

Comment: What is the difference between the two questions? The chain rule says $$\frac{\mathrm dS}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} + \frac{\partial S}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}$$

Comment: Because $S$ is not totally-differentiable, both sides are not equal.

Comment: $S(x(t),y(t))$ is not even continuous at $t=0$ and so ...

Comment: What's the task?